# Maximum bow and arrow (archery) damage

Tags: castle-crashers

What is the maximum possible bow and arrow damage?  I am not sure if it is dependent on character level or agility skill, but my question is more directed at max agility skill damage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the maximum bonus from items is 9: Black Mace(+6) or Sai(+6) and Meowburt(+3).  Additionally you gain 25 agility from levels, bringing the maximum agi to 36

Arrow damage is equal to 2 + Agility ([cite](http://www.zauron.net/downloads/castle_crashers_characters.txt)), bringing maximum damage to 38 (against an unarmored foe). Also, the arc of your arrows is not affected by Weapons or Orbs, so it caps out at 25.

Now damage dealt is the result of: Round(Floor(Damage of attack) x Damage Resistance Multiplier of defender)

In the case of players the Damage Resistance Multiplier is 1.2 - (0.01 x Defense).

It's worth noting that the real strength of a max agi character is the ability to fire arrows in rapid succession, thus being able to juggle opponents.